# pix[x,y] from PIL produces name error

Tags: python-2.7, python-imaging-library, pixel

I am a beginner programmer and I am trying to access pixel data from a picture using python. I want to eventually get the pixel data into an array. I searched the web for the code of how to do this and this is what I got:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/bw.png")
pix = im.load()
print pix[x,y]
pix[x,y] = value
```

It seems to work fine until I get to the print[x,y] line. I get an error saying "NameError: name 'x' is not defined". I have downloaded PIL 1.1.7.

Can anyone lend me a helping hand?

Answer (score 1):

Uh, you didn't define `x`, `y`, or `value`...maybe try defining those first? What pixel did you want to access?

Comment: try adding `x, y = 0, 0` before `print pix[x, y]`

Comment: Haha wow that was a stupid question by me. Thanks for the reply. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

```
im = Image.open("C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/bw.png")
x, y = 1, 2    #sample coordinates
print im.getpixel((x, y))
```

that should work, note that to `getpixel` method you pass one argument - a tuple